# How do I remove newlines from a String in Dart?

Tags: dart

How do I remove the newlines from a string in Dart?

For instance, I want to convert:

```
"hello\nworld"
```

to

```
"hello world"
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use replaceAll(pattern, replacement):

```dart
main() {
  var multiline = "hello\nworld";
  var singleline = multiline.replaceAll("\n", " ");
  print(singleline);
}
```

Comment: this won't work in all cases such as text spaced between 2 or more lines

Comment: The request was to remove newlines, and replace a newline with a space, and the code does that. If you have more specific requirements, you might have to do something more specific.

Answer (score 3):

[@SethLadd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123471/seth-ladd)'s answer is correct, but in a very basic example.

In the case of a multiline input with text like:

```
Hello, world!
{\n}
I like things:
- cats
- dogs
{\n}
I like cats, alot
{\n}
{\n}
and more cats
{\n}
{\n}
{\n}
. (ignore this dot)
```

In the case of the above, your string is represented like this:

```
Hello, world!\n\nI like things:\n- cats\n- dogs\n\nI like cats, alot\n\n\nand more cats\n\n\n\n
```

Using [@SethLadd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/123471/seth-ladd)'s solution, I will be left with:

```
Hello, world!I like things:- cats- dogsI like cats, alotand more cats
```

which is certainly not the desired outcome. I suggest using the commonly used regex approach of to tackle the problem.

Calling [.trim()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/String/trim.html) will remove the last 4 `\n` (and any `\n` infront too).

If one wishes, you could limit new lines to a single open line with something like

```
text.trim().replaceAll(RegExp(r'(\n){3,}'), "\n\n")
```

Comment: What if you want to replace only the single breaklines?

Comment: You'll actually be left with `Hello, world!  I like things: - cats - dogs  I like cats, alot  and more cats    ` since it replaces newlines with spaces. If that's not what is wanted for a particular use-case, it's important to specify clearly what it *is* wanted. Your code removes leading and trailing *whitespace*, not just newlines,  and then converts three or more adjacent newlines into two newlines. That's very different from the original request.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
multieLine.replaceAll(RegExp(r"\\n"), "");
```

when ever trying to remove anything that works with "" use "\" for that