# Remove \n from a given strings in dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart

Given a string

```
String item = 'Hello\nWorld'
```

I want a function that removes `\n` from the given string
Something like this

```
String newItem = removeBacklash(item);
print(newItem); // newItem will be 'HelloWorld'
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053114/how-do-i-remove-newlines-from-a-string-in-dart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.replaceAll()`

```dart
String removeBacklash(String data) => data.replaceAll("\n", "");
```

More about [String](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.4/dart-core/String-class.html)

Comment: I think OP intended for the \n to be replaced by a space

Comment: @NoahJoshua i thought  so,  but OP included desire result `HelloWorld`